# Sum cells with the same month

Tags: microsoft-excel

For example, I have the first two columns below and want to generate the 3rd.

```
     A             B         C
1    Date          Value     Sum with same month
2    2017-01-20    3         7
3    2017-01-25    4         7
4    2017-02-19    2         4
5    2017-02-19    2         4
```

I tried `SUMIF` but it only seems to be able to compare equality (same day), inequality (before/after), or a few other simple things. Is there a way to give it a criteria like

C2    `=SUMIF(A2:A5, MONTH(the cell in the range) = MONTH(A2), B2:B5)`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with SumProduct. Start in C2 and copy down.

```
=Sumproduct($B$2:$B$5*(Month($A$2:$A$5)=Month(A2)))
```

Note that there are no $ signs in the last reference to A2